# Apache2 websocket proxy fails

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I'm trying to proxy websockets through Apache 2.4. I found an online demo, and this is my config based off of it. I'm running an app that uses websockets on port 8089 and am using apache to proxy the site and the app.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerAlias mysitehere

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
        RewriteRule .* "ws://mysiteishere/$1" [P,L]

        ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8089/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8089/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The HTTP proxy works fine, but the websockets just seem to hang up and not connect. How could I fix this? All modules needed are installed and apache shows no abnormal errors.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is a non-routable IP adress, you can't use it to proxy your ws server. Please add the output of `netstat -tulpen | grep 8089` to check if the server is running on the same host.

Comment: `tcp6       0      0 :::8089                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          14304322   28562/MovieNight`

Comment: Should I listen on my public IPv4 address?

Comment: I am not sure about your config. But first, make sure the following apache modules are loaded: `proxy`, `proxy_http` and `proxy_wstunnel`

Comment: They are all enabled.